# SurveyMonkey api Coldfusion issue

Tags: api, coldfusion, surveymonkey

I'm having trouble getting the header param "Authorization" to work correctly using cfhttp and cfhttpparam.

The connection is working fine... I am getting out through our proxy so that's not the issue.

The api documentation states that "Authorization" in the header should be formatted as "Authorization:bearer XXXYYYZZ".

When I try to add the "bearer" with a space after it I get the following error:  {"status":3,"errmsg":"Expected object or value"}

When I do not add the prefix "bearer" at all I get the following error: 
{"status":1,"errmsg":"Invalid \"Authorization\" data in request header"}

I've tried "bearer XXXYYYZZ" and "bearer%20XXXYYYZZ" and "bearer XXXYYYZZ" as well with the same results.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

CODE:

```
<cfhttp 
    timeout="2000" 
    url="https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list/?api_key=xxxx"
    proxyserver="proxy.xxxx.com" 
    proxyport="8080" 
    method="post" 
    result="httpResponse" 
    charset="utf-8"
    throwonerror="Yes">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="bearer XXXYYYZZ">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#httpResponse#">
```

RESPONSE:

Charset UTF-8
ErrorDetail [empty string]
Filecontent {"status":1,"errmsg":"Invalid \"Authorization\" data in request header"}
Header HTTP/1.1 200 OK Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Cache-Control,Content-Language,Content-Type,Expires,Last-Modified,Pragma,Date,Content-Length Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2016 13:16:11 GMT Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) SM-Request-ID: 251952a7-9d21-470e-807d-9b48adf0892b X-Mashery-Message-ID: 9ebad058-e4e5-4cc9-b9cf-bf33dee9fbc6 X-Mashery-Responder: prod-j-worker-us-west-1b-58.mashery.com X-Plan-QPS-Allotted: 6 X-Plan-QPS-Current: 1 X-Plan-Quota-Allotted: 7000 X-Plan-Quota-Current: 5 X-Plan-Quota-Reset: Friday, January 29, 2016 12:00:00 AM GMT Content-Length: 72 Connection: Close
Mimetype application/json
Responseheader

struct

Access-Control-Expose-Headers Cache-Control,Content-Language,Content-Type,Expires,Last-Modified,Pragma,Date,Content-Length
Connection Close
Content-Length 72
Content-Type application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date Thu, 28 Jan 2016 13:16:11 GMT
Explanation OK
Http_Version HTTP/1.1
SM-Request-ID 251952a7-9d21-470e-807d-9b48adf0892b
Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Status_Code 200
X-Mashery-Message-ID 9ebad058-e4e5-4cc9-b9cf-bf33dee9fbc6
X-Mashery-Responder prod-j-worker-us-west-1b-58.mashery.com
X-Plan-QPS-Allotted 6
X-Plan-QPS-Current 1
X-Plan-Quota-Allotted 7000
X-Plan-Quota-Current 5
X-Plan-Quota-Reset Friday, January 29, 2016 12:00:00 AM GMT

Statuscode 200 OK
Text YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to send an empty JSON struct in the body. The API requires a JSON input, even if there are no parameters to be sent in. Just add another `cfhttpparam` of type `body` with a value of `{}`

```
<cfhttp 
    timeout="2000" 
    url="https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list/?api_key=xxxx"
    proxyserver="proxy.xxxx.com" 
    proxyport="8080" 
    method="post" 
    result="httpResponse" 
    charset="utf-8"
    throwonerror="Yes">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="bearer XXXYYYZZ">
    <cfhttpparam name="body" type="body" value="{}">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#httpResponse#">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfhttp 
    timeout="2000" 
    url="https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list/?api_key=xxxx"
    proxyserver="proxy.xxxx.com" 
    proxyport="8080" 
    method="post" 
    result="httpResponse" 
    charset="utf-8"
    throwonerror="Yes">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="bearer XXXYYYZZ">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam name="body" type="body" value="{}">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#httpResponse#">
```

Comment: So this is an almost exact duplicate of my answer above? Why not accept my original as the answer?

Comment: I also need to add:       <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />    in order to make it work.

Comment: Perhaps - I had it working without specifying Content-Type with my Survey Monkey API key. A comment saying as much would've been polite, and I would've edited the answer. Copy/pasting the answer using what I provided and not giving credit is kinda rude.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not 100% sure how stackoverflow and the ratings system works. I wasn't trying to not give you credit. I thought it was the goal to have the complete answer posted. You certainly lead me to the answer... no doubt about that. Thanks again for your help!